# Proxy authentication error in using add-apt-repository after exporting proxy settings in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, software-center, ppa, proxy, authentication

I am trying to add repositories through the terminal after exporting proxy settings.

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy":"port"
export https_proxy="https://username:password@proxy":"port"
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
```

the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1182, in do_open
 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 922, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 857, in send
  self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1223, in connect
  super().connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 837, in connect
  self._tunnel()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 820, in _tunnel
      message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in _get_https_content_py3
  lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 481, in _open'_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1225, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1184, in do_open
 raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 321, in get_ppa_info
  ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 91, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
  return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 87, in get_info_from_lp
  return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in _get_https_content_py3
  raise PPAException("Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, reason), e)
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~umang/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-stickynotes: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1182, in do_open
  h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 922, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 857, in send
  self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1223, in connect
  super().connect()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 837, in connect
  self._tunnel()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 820, in _tunnel
  message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 101, in _get_https_content_py3
  lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 481, in _open '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1225, in https_open
  context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1184, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 119, in <module>
  shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 837, in shortcut_handler
  ret = factory(shortcut)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 382, in shortcut_handler
  return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 346, in __init__
  info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 333, in get_ppa_info
  _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 292, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
  lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 87, in get_info_from_lp
  return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in _get_https_content_py3
  raise PPAException("Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, reason), e)
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~umang: Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'
```

Obviously, there is some problem with proxy authentication. How can this be fixed?

`apt-get`, Software Center and synaptic etc are all working with my proxy authentication. It's just this `add-apt-repository` command that is failing.

Comment: seems like a regression, my proxy env was set years ago, and had no problems such as this. I managed to unset proxy env, and it now works as expected (via transparent proxy)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you split your ports? Try this.

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:port/"
export https_proxy="https://username:password@proxy:port/"
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
```

Or add to `/etc/apt/apt.conf` this lines and relogin:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "http://username:password@proxy:port/";
Acquire::::Proxy "true";
```

Comment: tried that. didn't work.

Comment: I added lines for answer

Comment: tried that too. not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Run this before running the `apt` command.

Sometimes `apt` is ignoring `apt.conf`; in that case you need to explicitly export it:

```
export http_proxy=<YOUR PROXY>/;
export HTTP_PROXY=<YOUR PROXY>/;
export https_proxy=<YOUR PROXY>/;
export HTTPS_PROXY=<YOUR PROXY>/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Properly with PROXY URL & PORT

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy url>:<port>";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<proxy url>:<port>";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<proxy url>:<port>";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks:<proxy url>:<port>";
```

example:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://abc.com.net:8080";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://abc.com.net:8080";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://abc.com.net:8080";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks:abc.com.net:8080";
```

Enter port number exactly as mentioned in your network proxy script.

If your host machine is Windows 7  and Guest OS is Ubuntu then
you can download your network proxy script 
**Browser -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Under Use Automatic configuration Script -> copy URL**

And paste into the browser. Your script will be downloaded now you can copy PROXYURL & PORT from that script

and paste it into `/etc/apt/apt.conf`
on your Ubuntu Guest OS as root user. `apt.conf` does not exist you have to make it yourself.